# PHP file_get_contents() returning enable cookies?

Tags: php, http, get, file-get-contents

I'm trying to do a `file_get_contents()` on https://satoshidice.com/api/status and it's returning this - http://puu.sh/58lCb

```
print file_get_contents($this->base . 'status');
```

`$this->base` is satoshidice.com/api (with the http).

Why would it return what it is in the image posted above..?

Comment: Beeecause it's not your website and the server delivered to you a parsed respone to your request via HTTP, not as you expect by opening the file directly. After all, your maschine does not have access to the file system...

Comment: The `file_get_contents` call won't be sending any cookies, so it will look to the web server like a browser with cookies disabled.

Comment: It's an API it shouldn't need to send cookies I tried the answer below and it didn't work.

Comment: You are attempting to read another site's files without cookies enabled, as others are saying -- this won't work on that site, because it requires cookies.

Comment: I have cookies enabled and even when I visit it on a browser it works (with or without cookies enabled).

Answer (score 6):

Suggest you use cURL instead of the file_get_contents

```
$_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, './cookiePath.txt');
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, './cookiePath.txt');
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; InfoPath.1)');
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //new added
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$rtn = curl_exec( $_curl );
```

Updated:
added the 'CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION'

Explain:

For this host, it will check the cookie is exists or not.

In case the requested cookie does not exists, it will create cookie and generate the HTTP code 307 to redirect:

https://satoshidice.com/api/status?stage=1

Comment: While this is a good start, if the website requires cookies, as the response indicates, you will need to set up cookie handling as well before this actually solves the problem.

Comment: @JohnSmith for this host, added the 'CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION' for HTTP Code 307 redirect

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: url in